Proper dereferencing of Fortran double precision values in GDB
I am using Fortran double precision reals. gdb works correctly, e.g.
(gdb) p t(27,8,1)
$17 = 4816.0976560758863

Sometimes I need to watch addresses, so
(gdb) p &t(27,8,1)
$18 = (PTR TO -> ( real(kind=8) )) 0x7fffef16bcb0

To my dismay, examining the content of the address I get
(gdb) p *(real *)0x7fffef16bcb0

$22 = -nan(0x7d1430)

In other cases, I get some completely wrong value instead of nan.

p *(real(kind(0.0d0) *)0x7fffef16bcb0 or similar does not work either

using small scripts containing


define vpr
# print variable in e-format
p $arg0
printf "$arg0 %e\n",$arg0
end

or
define fpr
  p /s *(real *)$arg0
end

does not help either, as working with x (examine) does not.
Help would be appreciated!

Welcome, I suggest taking the [tour]. Why do you use (real *) when GDB says the address points to a real(kind=8)? What does "does not work either" exactly mean? What exact similar did you try? Did you try (double *) in the C language mode?

Dereferencing of addresses is a C concept, it does not directly exist in Fortran. In the C mode (set language C) you can use
print *(double *) address

In general, the examine memory command in GDB is x so you can use
x/fg address

(g for the giant size, see also What does gdb 'x' command do? ).
